# Plain TeX macros with \obeylines and no delimiters.

Tags: macros

How can I define a macro, say `\address`, so that I can use it like this:

```
\address
27/7 Montague Street
Edinburgh
```

and it would put the lines following it into another macro, say `\addrinfo` ? What I'm ultimately trying to do, is modify Knuth's letter macros so that I can specify the address once in the letter, and then produce an address in a different font. Currently I've got

```
\newbox\theiraddressbox
\def\address{\beginlinemode%                                                               
 \global\setbox\theiraddressbox=\vtop\bgroup\raggedright
  \hsize=\longindentation \everypar{\hangindent1cm}
  \def\endmode{\egroup\endgroup\bigskip\copy\theiraddressbox}}
```

but this means the address label is set in the same font.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use plain tex instead of, say, koma-script’s nice letter (`scrlttr2`) class?

Comment: Personal preference for plain TeX, born from a frustration with LaTeX not giving me enough freedom. I'm also aware that my understanding of plain TeX is less that I want it to be.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is to put each line into a separate definition as part of the definition of `\address`. In Knuth's letter format, he puts the first line of the address in the definition of `\addressee`.

The idea is to do this for the whole address. Then you'll have the definitions of  `\ToName, \ToStreet` etc to use afterwards in any way you like.

A minimal example to illustrate the idea is as follows:

```
\def\beginlinemode{\endmode\begingroup\obeylines\def\endmode{\par\endgroup}}
\let\endmode=\par
\def\address{\beginlinemode\getToAddress}

% Populates the \To* definitions.
{\obeylines\gdef\getToAddress#1
  #2
  #3
  #4
  {\gdef\ToName{#2\unskip}%
   \gdef\ToStreet{#3\unskip}%
   \gdef\ToCity{#4\unskip}%
   \def\beginletter{\endgroup\bigskip}}}


\address
Some Name
27/7 Montague Street
Edinburgh


\beginletter

And now you can use the different fields as you wish. For example:

\bigskip
\moveright2cm\vbox{\hbox{\ToName}\hbox{\ToStreet}\hbox{\ToCity}}
\bigskip

This letter is addressed to {\bf \ToName}.

\bye
```

You can also have a `\FromAddress` macro similar to `\address`, but whose ending markup is `\address` instead of `\beginletter`. So you'd start your letter like:

```
\FromAddress
My Name
My Street
My City

\address
To Name
To Street
To City

\beginletter

etc
```

Answer (score 2):

In effect, your `\address` macro is not undelimited: Somehow, the `\endmode` macro has to get called afterwards. In Knuth's letter macros, this job is done by the `\body` macro. So, what you can do is delimit the `\address` macro like this:

```
\def\address{\beginlinemode\getaddress}
\def\getaddress#1\body{\gdef\theaddress{#1}\body}
```

Then the macro `\theaddress` will contain the unformatted address. Hope you can work out the missing details.

Comment: Thanks. My original version put the desired text in a box which was specified as \vtop\bgroup. The desired text was delimited by a \egroup which got called with one of several macros e.g. \date or \body or \yourref - the definitions of which included a \egroup. Am I right in saying it isn't possible to do a similar trick with macro definitions ? e.g \def\addr{\bgroup} and \def\date{\egroup <rest of \date definition> } ?

Comment: @Harry Newton: Unfortunately, you can't use `\bgroup` and `\egroup` in this way. As you can read in the TeXbook in the bottom of page 275, `\def` needs explicit left and right braces.