# Simplify how I write my address in documents

Tags: best-practices

Often when writing letters and articles, I need to print my address at the beginning or end of the document. I do this in the following ugly way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent My name\\
\noindent My university\\
\noindent My department\\
\noindent My address\\
\noindent My e-mail\\
\end{document}
```

Clearly there must be a better way to do this than having to repeat `\noindent ... \\` for every line. I'm thinking I could define a new command `\myaddress` that will simply print all of those lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
% define address command here
\begin{document}
\myaddress
\end{document}
```

Or at the very least define a new environment that takes care of the indentation and line break:

```
\documentclass{article}
% define address environment here
\begin{document}
    \begin{address}
        My name
        My university
        My department
        My address
        My e-mail
    \end{address}
\end{document}
```

But I have no idea how to do either.

Comment: What does make you think that `\noindent` is necessary after the first line? It isn't. Of course, the last ``\\`` is not necessary either (better, it's wrong).

Comment: Unless I've overlooked something, you can also use `\obeylines` in the start of your macro definition rather than putting a ``\\`` after each line.

Comment: @ChrisS: I can't get that to work. Can you?

Comment: @Sverre: It turns out it was overlooking something: [`\obeylines` doesn't work in a macro definition](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65016/24113).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the suggestions here and on Ulrike's comment to [Cancel the use of \baselineskip when at the top of page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173027/cancel-the-use-of-baselineskip-when-at-the-top-of-page), the following seems to be a good solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\myaddress}{\par\vspace{\baselineskip}\vbox{\parindent = 0em%
    My name\\%
    My university\\%
    My department\\%
    My address\\%
    My e-mail}}
\begin{document}
\myaddress
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can easily do something as simple as

```
\newcommand\printmyaddress{%
\begingroup
\parindent 0pt
\myname       \par
\myuniversity \par
\mydepartment \par
\myaddress    \par
\myemail      \par
\endgroup}
```

and then set those macros accordingly.  Put it in a `.sty` file and you'd be good enough to go (assuming the formatting is done as you like it).

Maybe it's more fun to be more elaborate, however.  One idea would be a key-value approach that allows you to have default values that can be overriden piece by piece if you like.  There are many options this way; here's one that uses `l3keys`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xparse}

% from here to \ExplSyntaxOff, you could put this in a separate .sty
% to keep things tidy...
\ExplSyntaxOn
% get things set up with defaults:
\keys_define:nn { svdetails }
 {
  name       .tl_gset:N = \g_svdetails_name_tl,
  university .tl_gset:N = \g_svdetails_university_tl,
  department .tl_gset:N = \g_svdetails_department_tl,
  address    .tl_gset:N = \g_svdetails_address_tl,
  email      .tl_gset:N = \g_svdetails_email_tl,
% set the default values (change to real values) 
  name       .initial:n = NAMEDEFAULT,
  university .initial:n = UNIDEFAULT,
  department .initial:n = DEPTDEFAULT,
  address    .initial:n = ADDRESSDEFAULT,
  email      .initial:n = EMAILDEFAULT
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\biodetails}{ m }
 {
  \keys_set:nn { svdetails } { #1 }
 }

% How do we want things to look when printed? 
% (Nothing fancy here: just 'zero' the \parindent and print
% everything in a new paragraph. But it would be easy to change.)
\NewDocumentCommand{\printdetails}{ }
 {\begingroup
   \parindent 0pt
   \g_svdetails_name_tl       \par
   \g_svdetails_university_tl \par
   \g_svdetails_department_tl \par
   \g_svdetails_address_tl    \par
   \g_svdetails_email_tl      \par
   \endgroup}

\ExplSyntaxOff

% override document defaults; not strictly necessary since we
% already set defaults above...
\biodetails{
  name=Sverre Sverre,
  university=University of Somewhere,
  department=Department of XYZ,
%  address=Unknown Address,
  email=sverre@sverre.com,
}

\begin{document}

\printdetails

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\myaddress}{%
\begin{flushleft}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}%  For flushing at least a little bit
\begin{tabular}{l}
My Name \\
My university \\
My department \\
My address \\
My e-mail \\
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
}% End of \newcommand*

\begin{document}
  \myaddress
\end{document}
```

is a possible 'quick' solution. The linespacings can be set by redefinition of `\arraystretch` for example, if needed.

Comment: Using a ``tabular`` environment will, however, not flush the text to the margin. But I used your suggestion as a template, and (as a quick fix) put my entire address, with ``\noindent ...\\``, inside ``\newcommand{\myaddress}{}``.

Comment: @Sverre: Ok, I see, that I missed flushing to the margin... perhaps, one could do with setting `\tabcolsep` to zero.

Comment: @Christian Instead of changing a global variable to a bad value, disable the seps locally by changing `{l}` to `{@{}l@{}}`

Comment: @tohecz: That's a nice idea, but if I use another table after my `\myaddress` command, the `tabcolsep` value is restored to original value -- it is changed within a `\newcommand`.

Comment: @Christian Your setting to `\tabcolsep` is indeed local because it's issued inside a `flushleft` environment (not because it's changed within `\newcommand`). But the `@{}l@{}` method is much easier.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, you are right. The column modifier solution is indeed easier and does not depend on strange length settings

Answer (score 3):

A left-aligned `\Longstack` will work here.  Depending on how you need the vertical placement of the item, a `\Longunderstack` may be preferable to `\Longstack`, though in many situations, it won't matter which is chosen.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\noindent\Longstack[l]{
 My name\\
 My university\\
 My department\\
 My address\\
 My e-mail}
\textbf{versus}
\Longunderstack[l]{
 My name\\
 My university\\
 My department\\
 My address\\
 My e-mail}
\end{document}
```

[image]