# Cancel the use of \baselineskip when at the top of page

Tags: spacing, automation

I've defined a macro `\myaddress` which prints my address at the end of a document, cf. [Simplify how I write my address in documents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160927/simplify-how-i-write-my-address-in-documents). That macro includes the use of `\vspace{\baselineskip}` to separate it from previous text.

But when that address happens to be the first thing on a new page, it looks wrong that there is a baselineskip at the top of the page, as seen in the picture below. How can I redefine my macro so that `\vspace{\baselineskip}` is canceled out when the address ends up at the top of a new page?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe, pass]{geometry}
\newcommand{\myaddress}{\parindent=0pt\vbox{% \vbox prevents page break
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    My name\\
    My university\\
    My department\\
    My address\\
    My e-mail}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\myaddress
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you put the vspace before the box? `\par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent\vbox{\noindent...` You could also use `\\*` to prevent linebreaks so the box is not really necessary.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That is replace every ``\\`` with ``\\*``? Also, what is the purpose of using ``\noindent`` twice? It seems to suffice with one.

Comment: When you use \vbox you don't need the outer \noindent as \vbox doesn't start a paragraph. But \vbox is a tex primitive and \parbox or a tabular would be better and in this case you would need the outer \noindent.

Comment: I wasn't able to detect any difference between using one or two ``\noindent`` in this or other documents. By the way, using ``\noindent`` worked fine in this MWE, but not in my actual articles, since all lines except the first were indented. Using ``\parindent=0em`` fixed that issue, though.

Comment: The spacing will be wrong (or at least inconsistent) if you use `\vbox` as it will be higher than baseline so introduce lineskip glue. (also it is not a latex command). If you want a box use `\parbox[t]{..}{...}` so that the spacing above the box is determined from teh top row, but simpler not to have a box and to use `\\*` to stop page breaks.

Comment: Could one of you (@UlrikeFischer, @DavidCarlisle) add an answer with a MWE that I can accept?