# obeylines command is not working inside a definition

Tags: macros, catcodes

The problem is that `\obeylines` macro is not working while it's inside `\def`

Compare:

```
\long\def\linesaver#1{\obeylines#1}
\linesaver{
Test1
Test2
}
```

VS

```
{
\obeylines
Test3

Test4
Test5
}
```

First does not saving newlines, but second does. Why?

Disregard targets i'm trying to reach - consider i'm just trying to understand how exactly tex works under the hood.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\obeylines` has no effect when used in the argument to another command, because it works by changing category codes.

Comment: Maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65010/command-obeylines-in-a-macro helps?

Comment: @jarauh helps a bit, but if I implement \linesaver command in a similar style like \makeAddress and put in inside another block like a \something{\linesaver{...}} it's not working again. Probably need much more complicated hack or workaround.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: What do you [really](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2449/5763) want to achieve?

Comment: @user1038085 Because the answering here is blocked, I do answer only in this comment. The `\obeylines` macro changes catcodes and you must read the text from file *after* these catcodes are changed. And don't forget to return the catcode setting back. For example you can put the whole processing into a group. Your intend can be implemented by `\def\linesaver{\bgroup\obeylines\linesaverA}` `\def\linesaverA#1{#1\egroup}`.

Answer (score 3):

Let's see what happens with the call

```
\long\def\linesaver#1{\obeylines#1}

\linesaver{
Test1
Test2
}
```

Since `\linesaver` has one argument, TeX absorbs it and performs tokenization; so the end-of-lines get changed into space tokens *before* `\obeylines` enters into action. It does when the argument has already been absorbed, so there's no `^^M` in the argument and, moreover, changing category code has no effect on tokens that have already been scanned by TeX.

The only effect is that `\obeylines` will be in force from now on, because there's no grouping.

Comment: Does the situation improve if you `\def\linesaver#1{\scantokens{\obeylines#1}}`?

Comment: @erreka No. The category code 5 line terminators will already have been converted and there's no way to resurrect them.